# hsqldb properties

Tags: hsqldb

I am using hsqldb which is having the following settings in the properties file (not set by me)

```
hsqldb.cache_size_scale=8
readonly=false
hsqldb.nio_data_file=true
hsqldb.cache_scale=14
version=1.8.0
hsqldb.default_table_type=memory
hsqldb.cache_file_scale=1
modified=yes
hsqldb.cache_version=1.7.0
hsqldb.original_version=1.8.0
hsqldb.compatible_version=1.8.0
```

The db started giving errors in logs
`java.sql.SQLException: S1000 General error java.util. NoSuchElementException`

Some searching on google pointed me that this is because the limit of the .data file has been reached. The size of the .data file is around 0.7gb.
If i increase the cache_file_size , will the above error disappear

```
hsqldb.default_table_type=memory
hsqldb.cache_file_scale=1
```

If `hsqldb.cache_file_scale=3.`
Does this mean that database is in memory and will require 3GB. If memory is an issue how can be reduced ?

Answer (score 0):

The current setting allows up to 2GB in the data file.

I suggest you perform a SHUTDOWN SCRIPT to clear up any problems. If you have further problems, contact the HSQLDB project.

Comment: hsqldb.cache_file_scale=1, then how 2GB ? Will it occupy xGB in memory ?

Comment: This is the default setting and the Guide says the max size is 2GB by default.